# rvest to collect html_elements from a list of "ids"

Tags: r, rvest, rselenium

I am trying to read in some data from a website. I want to collect the links of the `cardboxes`.

I can run the following code:

```
page2 %>% 
  html_nodes(".re-CardPackMinimal-info-container") %>%
  html_attr(name = "href") %>% 
  paste("https://www.fotocasa.es", ., sep = "")
```

Which gives me a list of 27 items on the page, however, there are 30 items I want to collect, so I am missing some. Upon closer inspection I see that the page contains the following `re-CardPackMinimal`, `re-AdvertisingNativeListing-container` and `re-CardPackPremium`, `re-AdvertisingTop2Listing`.

So what I want to do is to read over these "ids" and read in the data. I could manually add them in as the following:

```
page2 %>% 
  html_nodes(".re-CardPackMinimal")

page2 %>% 
  html_nodes(".re-CardPackPremium")
```

etc.

But I was wondering if I could collect the "ids" first and then use this to collect each data point.

What I am able to get it the following:

```
page2 %>% 
  html_nodes(".re-SearchResult") %>% 
  html_children() %>%
  html_attr(name = "class")



 [1] "re-CardPackMinimal"                    "re-CardPackMinimal"                    "re-CardPackMinimal"                   
 [4] "re-CardPackMinimal"                    "re-AdvertisingTop2Listing"             "re-CardPackMinimal"                   
 [7] "re-CardPackMinimal"                    "re-CardPackMinimal"                    "re-CardPackMinimal"                   
[10] "re-AdvertisingNativeListing-container" "re-CardPackMinimal"                    "re-CardPackMinimal"                   
[13] "re-CardPackMinimal"                    "re-CardPackMinimal"                    "re-CardPackMinimal"                   
[16] "re-CardPackMinimal"                    "re-CardPackMinimal"                    "re-CardPackMinimal"                   
[19] "re-CardPackMinimal"                    "re-CardPackMinimal"                    "re-CardPackMinimal"                   
[22] "re-CardPackMinimal"                    "re-CardPackMinimal"                    "re-CardPackPremium"                   
[25] "re-CardPackPremium"                    "re-CardPackMinimal"                    "re-CardPackMinimal"                   
[28] "re-CardPackMinimal"                    "re-CardPackAdvance"                    "re-CardPackMinimal"                   
[31] "re-CardPackMinimal"                    "re-CardPackMinimal"
```

So, I want to take each of these and collect their corresponding URL, title etc. There are 30 "cards" on the page with 2 advertisements `re-AdvertisingNativeListing-container` and `re-AdvertisingTop2Listing`. I would like to distinguish between the normal listing, advertisement and premium if possible.

Code:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2)
library(stringr)
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)
openAndScrollPage <- function(link){
  
  driver = rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"))
  remDr <- driver[["client"]]
  remDr$navigate(link)
  
  #accept cookies
  remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", '/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/footer/div/button[2]')$clickElement()
  
  # order by most recent
  remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', '//*[@id="App"]/div[2]/div[1]/main/div/div[3]/div/div/select/option[3]')$clickElement()
  
  #after navigating and accepting cookie, we shall scroll bit by bit 
  for(i in 1:30){ 
    print(paste("Scrolling for: ", i, " seconds", sep = ""))
    remDr$executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500);")
    Sys.sleep(1)
  }
  #get nodes of all houses
  html_full_page = remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
    read_html()
  
  return(html_full_page)
}

link2 = "https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/la-nova-esquerra-de-l-eixample/l"
page2 = link %>% 
  openAndScrollPage()

page2 %>% 
  html_nodes(".re-SearchResult") %>% 
  html_children() %>%
  html_attr(name = "class")
```

Comment: Does the scrolling work as expected?

Comment: Yes, on my side it scrols until the end of the page and loads all of it

Comment: The classes you are looking at include elements other than the listing "cards". The 30 listings all have the same premium class. I wondered if the other classes were associated with divisions of listings within the page but there are more than 2 listings above the top 2 ads div for example.